# How to queue a work item in windows 8

Tags: multithreading, windows-store-apps

When I would fetch data of a server Under a Desktop App, I used to Queuing for execution the task that fethcing data by passing the WaitCallback delegate to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FetchServerCallback));
```

But on a Windows store app, how I can do to get the same result ?

Comment: Top google hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465290.aspx

Comment: thanks, this page help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Task.Run(() => { /* your code */ });`

Or even

```
await Task.Run(() => { /* your code */ });
// TODO this code runs after "your code" has been processed
```

to do other stuff after your code has been processed...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382.aspx